# no ocijdbc12 in java.library.path sqldeveloper mac os

Tags: macos, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to get SQLDeveloper to work on my Mac laptop.  I need to make a TNS connection but whenever I try to create one I get the error message: `no ocijdbc12 in java.library.path`.

[image]

I have latest instantclient installed and I only see these files:

```
instantclient_11_2:
total 380640
-rw-rw-rw-@ 1 red  staff        484 Apr 10  2014 BASIC_README
-rwxrwxrwx@ 1 red  staff      14348 Apr 10  2014 adrci
-rwxrwxrwx@ 1 red  staff      40768 Apr 10  2014 genezi
-r-xr-xr-x@ 1 red  staff   66167420 Feb  7  2014 libclntsh.dylib.11.1
-r-xr-xr-x@ 1 red  staff    2817872 Jan 29  2014 libnnz11.dylib
-r-xr-xr-x@ 1 red  staff    1897664 Feb  7  2014 libocci.dylib.11.1
-rwxrwxrwx@ 1 red  staff  118707148 Apr 10  2014 libociei.dylib
-r-xr-xr-x@ 1 red  staff     159004 Jan  7  2014 libocijdbc11.dylib
-r--r--r--@ 1 red  staff    2091135 Jan 28  2014 ojdbc5.jar
-r--r--r--@ 1 red  staff    2739616 Jan 28  2014 ojdbc6.jar
-rwxrwxrwx@ 1 red  staff     162380 Apr 10  2014 uidrvci
-r--r--r--@ 1 red  staff      66779 Jan  7  2014 xstreams.jar
```

There's a `libocijdbc11.dylib` but no `libocijdbc12.dylib`.  What's up with that?

Comment: Why use the tick driver (=TNS connection) at all? The thin driver (connection type=basid) which **only** needs `ojdbc6.jar` is recommended anyway.

Comment: That worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After a recent JAVA upgrade, my SqlDeveloper install stopped working, errors related to :

The native OCI driver could not be loaded. The system property java.library.path contains the entries from the environment variable 'DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH'  check it to verify that the expected native library directory /usr/lib/java is present and precedes any other client installations.

- I upgraded to SqlDeveloper 18.1.0  =  no luck.
- I tried many fixes -  modifying '/.sqldeveloper/18.1.0/product.conf', futzing with $PATH, etc -  they all failed
- FINALLY - I upgraded the instant client to instantclient_12_2  IT WORKED!

Note - the place you set environment vars is now:  ${HOME}/.sqldeveloper//env.sh

in my case, /Users/REDACTED/.sqldeveloper/18.1.0/env.sh contains:

```
export TNS_ADMIN="${HOME}/Downloads/instantclient_12_2" 
export  DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$TNS_ADMIN  
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$TNS_ADMIN 
export SQLPATH=$TNS_ADMIN 

if ! echo $PATH | fgrep "${DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH}"  /dev/null ; then 
   export PATH="${DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH}:${PATH}" 
fi
```

This (using env.sh)  is better than cluttering up your .bashrc files

Answer (score 0):

My Solution:

Just use the setting in SQLDeveloper:
Tools > Preferences > Database > Advanced > Tnsnames Directory

Click Browse to select the location of the parent folder of your tnsnames file.